# Restructure pandas dataframe for Network Graph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am working on building a pandas data frame to make a network graph.  My data frame currently looks like this:

```
Group1 Group2 Group3 Asset
A      A      A      MI
A      A      A      JI
A      A      A      MI
A      A      A      JI
A      A      A      MI
A      A      B      MI
A      A      C      MI
A      A      C      PA
A      A      C      MI
A      A      C      PA
A      A      C      MI
A      A      C      PA
A      A      C      MI
A      A      C      PA
A      A      C      MI
```

and I want to manipulate it to look like this:

```
Source Target Weight
MI     JI     1
MI     MI     1
MI     PA     1
JI     MI     1
PA     MI     1
```

Essentially I would like to break up the Asset column into 2 columns of each possible combination for every unique pairing of Group 1, 2, and 3.  The first part of the pairing would make up the Source column and the 2nd part of the pairing would make up the Target column.  And for this minimal example, it's just group 3 that varies.  The weight column represents the sum of total pairings of individual assets.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?  Any help would be appreciated!

Here is some sample code to generate the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group1': ['A','A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A'],
                   'Group2': ['A','A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A'],
                   'Group3': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
                   'Asset': ['MI','JI','MI','JI','MI','MI','MI','PA','MI','PA','MI','PA','MI','PA','MI']
                   
                   })
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the conversion from Group/Assets to 'Source' and 'Target'? You should clarify that in the description.

Comment: I guess I understand now. Anyway, it could be more explicit. Does which asset   is 'Source' and which one is the 'Target' matters? Or the graph is undirected?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It doesn't matter - just want to have every possible combo of Asset pairings for each grouping of (Group1, 2, and 3).  And no, it is intended to be an undirected graph.

Comment: Actually, after reading it a 2nd time,  I still don't get the expected output. Why there are no ('PA', 'PA'), ('JI', 'JI') pairs coming from the 1st and 3rd groups? I understand that ('MI', 'MI') comes from 2nd. But why the others don't count as unique pairs? Besides, can you elaborate on the computation of the  'Weight' column? Maybe describing the result through pseudo-code would help.

Comment: So for this example, don't worry so much about Groups 1 and 2.  For every different value of Group 3, I want to list the possible combinations of values within Asset, so for Group 3-Value A, we have MI-JI and JI-MI, and then for Group 3-Value B, it's just MI-MI and then for Group 3-Value C, it's MI-PA, PA-MI.  And the weight should be the total # of times those pairings appear.  For this minimal example, it should just be 1 each.

Comment: Note that I was referring (A, A, A), (A, A, B) and (A, A, C) as the  1st, 2nd, and 3rd groups, respectively. I wasn't referring to the 'Group' columns. The explanation confirms my interpretation of the problem. What I don't understand is why PA-PA and  JI-JI are not valid pairs but MI-MI is.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  That's on me for not fully explaining that.  I interpreted it as there has to be a single value of either PA or JI for a given Group3 value for that to occur.

Comment: I just posted my solution, see if you understand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group1': ['A','A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A'],
                   'Group2': ['A','A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A'],
                   'Group3': ['A','A','A','A','A','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
                   'Asset': ['MI','JI','MI','JI','MI','MI','MI','PA','MI','PA','MI','PA','MI','PA','MI']
                   })

def assets_pairs(assets_group):
    unique_assets = set(assets_group)
    if len(unique_assets) == 1:
        x = assets_group.iat[0]  # get the only unique asset
        pairs = [[x, x]]
    else:
        pairs = it.permutations(unique_assets, r=2)  # get all the unique pairs without repeated elements
    return pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['Source', 'Target']) 
   
df_pairs = (
    df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'])['Asset']
      .apply(assets_pairs)   # create asset pairs per group 
      .groupby(['Source', 'Target'], as_index=False)  # compute the weights  by 
      .agg(Weights = ('Source', 'size'))              # counting the unique ('Source', 'Target') pairs
)

>>> df_pairs

  Source Target  Weights
0     JI     MI        1
1     MI     JI        1
2     MI     MI        1
3     MI     PA        1
4     PA     MI        1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a transposed view of the data:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d, v = [*zip(*[df[i] for i in df])], []
for i in range(len(d)-1):
   if (k:=(d[i][-1], d[i+1][-1])) not in v:
      v.append(k)

r = [tuple([*k, 1]) for k in v]
```

Output:

```
[('MI', 'JI', 1), ('JI', 'MI', 1), ('MI', 'MI', 1), ('MI', 'PA', 1), ('PA', 'MI', 1)]
```